# Vaadin get the table contents into a Map

Tags: java, vaadin

I am kinda new to Vaadin, and already went through their book. My question is about an editable table and how to get the values out of it when it is changed.

So basically what I have is a simple table and I fill this with a HashMap. So edit buttons make the fields editable, and add line button adds a line. The implementation is straightforward. But what I did not manage is the update button, because when I add a line or edit some field I want to get all the changed keys and values **as pairs** into my hashmap again and do sth with that.

I know that `Property.ValueChangeListener` gives you all the cells that changed, but what I need is information about the whole row - not a single cell. For example when `val2` is changed to `val22`, I want to update my hashmap according to it. Therefore I need to get `key2` as well. Simply, I want to get the whole line when something is changed on that. Any ideas on that?

And my UI looks as following and I am using Vaadin 6:
[image]

Comment: You could take a look at [Map Container](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/mapcontainer:vaadin), an add-on I wrote that serves as an adapter between `HashMap` and Vaadin's `Container`. It is far from perfect, but it should at least get you started. Feel free to raise any issues you have with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might need such a thing I have found a workaround:

```
// I needed to fill the table with an IndexedContainer
final IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
// table headers
container.addContainerProperty("Metadata Key", String.class, null);
container.addContainerProperty("Metadata Value", String.class, null);

// Now fill the container with my hashmap (objectMetadatas) and at the end we will add the container to the table
int i = 0;
for (String k : objectMetadatas.keySet()) {
    Integer rowId = new Integer(i);
    container.addItem(rowId);
    container.getContainerProperty(rowId, "Metadata Key").setValue(k);
    container.getContainerProperty(rowId, "Metadata Value").setValue(objectMetadatas.get(k));
    i++;
}

// then added a ValueChangeListener to the container
container.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
         Property p = event.getProperty(); // not necessary
             System.out.println(p);        // not necessary
    }
});

// add the the button to update the table and get the changed values into your hashmap
buttonUpdate.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Collection i = tableMetadata.getContainerDataSource().getItemIds();
        for (int x = 0; x < i.size(); x++) {
            // Items in Vaadin represent rows, since I have two columns
            // i have only two values in my row as following: "row1 row2"
            // if you have four columns on your table 
            // your item will look like this: "row1 row2 row3 row4"
            Item it=myTable.getContainerDataSource().getItem(x);
            // thats why I am splitting it
            String[] row= it.toString().split(" ");
            map.put(row[0], row[1]);
        }
        // Now all changed values are in your map! 
        // Do sth with that map
    }
});

// Finally do not forget to add that container to your table
tableMetadata.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

That's all! Hope it will help to someone! And please if you find a better way please post it.