# How to display list of java.util.Properties object to Vaadin table ? Which container could help directly without looping?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have collection of java.util.Properties objects, where each object contains key and values.

For example, my list has two properties object as below,

[{name=A, type=B, value=C},{name=D, type=E, value=F}]

They should be displayed in the Table as

```
name type value

A     B    C
D     E    F
```

I can loop thru each property object and add it to the table as described in the below url

[Vaadin get the table contents into a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722298/vaadin-get-the-table-contents-into-a-map)

or convert the each property object to a bean and add it to table using BeanItemContainer.

Is there anyway to directly set the list of properties to container and add the container to the table ?

I am using Vaadin 8.6.4 where I can also use Vaadin 7 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a Vaadin 8 `Grid`. If I understood correctly, something like this could work (untested code)

```
Grid<Properties> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addColumn(props -> props.get("name")).setHeader("Name");
grid.addColumn(props -> props.get("type")).setHeader("Type");
grid.addColumn(props -> props.get("value")).setHeader("Value");

grid.setItems(myListOfProperties);
```

Comment: Exactly, it would be something like that. Here is one project that demonstrates how to use Grid in Vaadin 8 without bean https://github.com/TatuLund/GridFlip/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/gridflip/MyUI.java

Comment: Does it mean that it is not possible using Table component in Vaadin 7.x ?

Comment: There is Table component in Vaadin 7.x, but not in Vaadin 8.x